# FRP Interstellar, transforming, chaining signals

Tags: swift, frp

Suppose there are two asyncronous requests to an API which need to be executed in sequence. 
The result of the first request is dictionary which is used by second request in order to get the final dictionary.
Interstellar (https://github.com/JensRavens/Interstellar) enables chaining the asyncronous requests in a way to execute them one after another in sequence:
For example:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String: AnyObject]

func create(parameters: JSONDictionary, completion: Result<JSONDictionary> -> Void) {
    Request.POST("objects", parameters: parameters, completion: completion)
}

func verify(parameters: JSONDictionary, completion: Result<JSONDictionary> -> Void) {
    guard let id = parameters["id"] as? String else {
        let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 401, userInfo: nil)
        completion(.Error(error))
        return
    }
    Request.POST(String(format: "objects/%@/verify", id), parameters: nil, completion: completion)
}
```

"create" needs to be executed first and the result dictionary will be used to execute "verify":
This works great:

```
address.flatMap(Address.create).flatMap(Address.verify)
.next { dictionary in
    expectation.fulfill()
}
.error { error in
    print("There was a an error: \(message)")
}
address.update(self.parameters)
```

And with code bellow (from Interstellar slides):

```
infix operator >>> { associativity left precedence 160 }
func >>> <A, B> (left: Signal<A>, right: A->Result<B>) -> Signal<B> {
   return left.flatMap(right)
}
func >>> <A, B> (left: Signal<A>, right: (A, (Result<B> -> Void)) -> Void) -> Signal<B> {
   return left.flatMap(right)
}
func >>> <A, B> (left: Signal<A>, right: A -> B) -> Signal<B> {
   return left.flatMap(right)
}
```

it's possible to use:

```
address >>> Address.create >>> Address.verify
```

which is even more clear. But, what if the verify is defined as (accepting id instead of dictionary):

```
func verify2(id: String, completion: Result<[String: String]> -> Void) { ... }
```

in order to chain it, I defined another func:

```
static func idValue(dictionary: JSONDictionary, completion: Result<String> -> Void) { ... )
```

which basically unpacks value of id key from the dictionary (transforms dictionary to string) than I can use:

```
address >>> Address.create >>> Address.idValue >>> Address.verify2
```

Is this common practice in FRP? Can I avoid the step in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great to hear you're using this library. And yes - that's the way it's supposed to work. Here are some small ideas how to make it a bit easier to read:

- custom operators were removed before releasing the lib, mostly because developers didn't like it (and they changed my mind, too. `flatMap` is way more readable in complex cases)
- one of the main ideas of functional programming is to make the type system work for you. If `Address.create` returns an `Address`-struct, the next call can just use the `id`-property of it. Using json as arguments almost never works as soon as the communication gets complex.
- another idea would be to use a `Lens` as Chris Eidhof explains in [Lenses in Swift](http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/lenses-in-swift.html).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the Lenses link, will play with it to test the idea